# NetworkManger doesn't open Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: network-manager

running `sudo NetworkManager` from the terminal outputs no errors, but also doesn't open a window or anything to use.

I am running BSPWM

I've also tried running it from Rofi, and the same thing occurs, no window actually opens.

running `sudo gnome-control-center network` in terminal outputs the following errors:

```
** (gnome-control-center:16538): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-3AhNpWuGp2: Connection refused

** (gnome-control-center:16538): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher gufw (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:16538): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher landscape-client-settings (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:16538): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:16538): WARNING **: Could not find settings panel "network"
```

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManager is not an application in Ubuntu and you cannot open it like that. It's a daemon/service that manages network connections.

It's started during boot, but if you want to restart it, you can type e.g.:

`sudo service network-manager restart`